# Flex Webchat friendlyName for Chatbot

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat, web-chat

I am trying to customize the `flex webchat` by sending the messages to a chatbot and have it route to the Live Agents based on the intents. Is there any way to update the friendlyName for the chatbot and also override the friendly name when the live agent is connected?

```
yourDefaultName: 'You',
theirDefaultName: 'ChatBot',                         
yourFriendlyNameOverride: true,
theirFriendlyNameOverride: true
```

The above settings work fine to override the friendly name when the live agent takes over the chat but does not work for the chatbot. Chatbot name by default looks something like this.

> CH85eb5b4f05dd4282a253bb3ab8fc6a78 03:37 PM Please wait while I
>   connect you with the agent.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out.. The issue was fixed by updating the "Send Message From" in the studio widget and it works perfectly now.

Cheers!
kiran